# Calculate time using the last two dates with a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate a time difference by a record_id using two consecutive dates but only if the category has a specific value that is repeated (category == "1").

My data frame is

```
structure(list(record_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P4", "P4", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5"), visit_date = structure(c(1547596800, 1548806400, 1552608000, 1560988800, 1611187200, 1576195200, 1577664000, 1579132800, 1594857600, 1609459200, 1577836800,1580515200, 1612137600, 1548979200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1617235200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
category = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to create a variable (time) as a date difference between visit_dates by record IDs ONLY if they have two consecutive category==1.

Like this:

```
structure(list(record_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P4", "P4"), visit_date = structure(c(1547596800, 1548806400, 1552608000, 1560988800, 1611187200, 1576195200, 1577664000, 1579132800, 1594857600, 1609459200, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1612137600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), category = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), time = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 366, 366, 366)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Note that P5 the date difference is with the first category 1 and the last category 1

Comment: It's not clear how you want the P5 result calculated. The results for P5 are not included in your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

### base R

```r
consec2 <- function(x, n = 2L) {
  r <- rle(x)
  ind <- (r$values & r$lengths >= n)
  r$values[!ind] <- FALSE
  inverse.rle(r)
}
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$record_id, function(z) {
  cat1 <- consec2(z$category == 1)
  z$time <- if (sum(cat1) > 1) {
    as.numeric(diff(range(z$visit_date[cat1])), units = "days") else NA_real_
  z
}))
# # A tibble: 17 x 4
#    record_id visit_date          category  time
#  * <chr>     <dttm>                 <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 P1        2019-01-16 00:00:00        0    NA
#  2 P1        2019-01-30 00:00:00        0    NA
#  3 P1        2019-03-15 00:00:00        0    NA
#  4 P2        2019-06-20 00:00:00        0    NA
#  5 P2        2021-01-21 00:00:00        1    NA
#  6 P3        2019-12-13 00:00:00        0   169
#  7 P3        2019-12-30 00:00:00        0   169
#  8 P3        2020-01-16 00:00:00        0   169
#  9 P3        2020-07-16 00:00:00        1   169
# 10 P3        2021-01-01 00:00:00        1   169
# 11 P4        2020-01-01 00:00:00        0   366
# 12 P4        2020-02-01 00:00:00        1   366
# 13 P4        2021-02-01 00:00:00        1   366
# 14 P5        2019-02-01 00:00:00        0   396
# 15 P5        2020-03-01 00:00:00        1   396
# 16 P5        2020-04-01 00:00:00        1   396
# 17 P5        2021-04-01 00:00:00        1   396
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(
    r = consec2(category == 1),
    time = if (any(r)) as.numeric(diff(range(visit_date[r])), units = "days") else NA_real_
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 17 x 5
#    record_id visit_date          category r      time
#    <chr>     <dttm>                 <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
#  1 P1        2019-01-16 00:00:00        0 FALSE    NA
#  2 P1        2019-01-30 00:00:00        0 FALSE    NA
#  3 P1        2019-03-15 00:00:00        0 FALSE    NA
#  4 P2        2019-06-20 00:00:00        0 FALSE    NA
#  5 P2        2021-01-21 00:00:00        1 FALSE    NA
#  6 P3        2019-12-13 00:00:00        0 FALSE   169
#  7 P3        2019-12-30 00:00:00        0 FALSE   169
#  8 P3        2020-01-16 00:00:00        0 FALSE   169
#  9 P3        2020-07-16 00:00:00        1 TRUE    169
# 10 P3        2021-01-01 00:00:00        1 TRUE    169
# 11 P4        2020-01-01 00:00:00        0 FALSE   366
# 12 P4        2020-02-01 00:00:00        1 TRUE    366
# 13 P4        2021-02-01 00:00:00        1 TRUE    366
# 14 P5        2019-02-01 00:00:00        0 FALSE   396
# 15 P5        2020-03-01 00:00:00        1 TRUE    396
# 16 P5        2020-04-01 00:00:00        1 TRUE    396
# 17 P5        2021-04-01 00:00:00        1 TRUE    396
```

Comment: the OP state consecutive so I assume need to check that two `category == 1` is next to each other

Comment: WOW! Thanks! @r2evans and SinhNguyen